# Replacing URL when append

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm have a problem with my code , I think is logic problem, but the Master's can open my eyes... The program is duplicating the url3 when executing. I'd would realy like and need some help. I'm posting only the playground code, but if someone wish I can share the github code.

```
import UIKit

class AppPhotos: NSObject {
    var data_consulta: String?
    var apps: [App]?
    var type: String?

    static func testePhotos() {
        var fotos = [AppPhotos]()

        let teste = true
        if teste {
            let appPhotos = AppPhotos()
            var apps = [App]()
            let app = App()

            app.url = NSURL(string: "https://url1") as URL?
            apps.append(app)
            appPhotos.data_consulta = "1"
            appPhotos.apps = apps
            fotos.append(appPhotos)
        }

        if teste {
            let appPhotos = AppPhotos()
            var apps = [App]()

            let app = App()
            app.url = NSURL(string: "https://url2") as URL?

            apps.append(app)
            app.url = NSURL(string: "https://url3") as URL?
            apps.append(app)

            appPhotos.data_consulta = "2"
            appPhotos.apps = apps

            fotos.append(appPhotos)
        }

        for line in fotos {
            for url in line.apps! {
                print(url.url ?? "")
            }
        }
    }
}

class App: NSObject {
    var photo_original:UIImage?
    var url:URL?
}

AppPhotos.testePhotos()
```

Printing :

```
https://url1
https://url3
https://url3

will be 

https://url1
https://url2
https://url3
```

What I need, something this:

```
[ 
    data_consulta : 1,
        app : [ "https://url1" ],
    data_consulta : 2,
        app : [ "https://url2", "https://url3" ]
]
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSURL`? Just use `URL`.

Answer (score 3):

What happens is:

```
class App {
    var url:URL?
}
var apps = [App]()

let app = App() //app1 created

app.url = URL(string: "https://url2")
apps.append(app)
// apps contains [app1] here

app.url = URL(string: "https://url3") // changes url of app1 ...
apps.append(app) // and adds the same app (app1) again
// apps contains [app1, app1] here
```

To fix this, you have to create a second app:

```
let app = App() //app1 created

app.url = URL(string: "https://url2")
apps.append(app)
// apps contains [app1] here

let app2 = App() //app2 created
app2.url = URL(string: "https://url3") // changes url of app2
apps.append(app2)
// apps contains [app1, app2] here
```

---

Update:

Or for 30 apps:

```
let numApps = 30

for i in 1...numApps {
    let app = App()
    app.url = URL(string: "https://url\(i)")
    apps.append(app)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you explanation :-) . But, if I have 30 app,  I'll need to create 30 new variables, can I create a function to create some new ramdon app if necessary  ?

Comment: Yes you would. Or, if the number in the URL increases, see the updated answer.

Comment: OK, I will try to do something, because the url does not increses, is a NSUUID().uuidString like this :  
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apportho-d6917.appspot.com/o/f840BfKPF6YjKz7xy13Rurq6Khh1%2F61ACAEB6-B27E-4C84-AF0A-0A6160D2D1DB.jpg?alt=media&token=5196fb65-1f03-4910-a4b8-839d2a9dff66

Answer (score 2):

No one is responding WHY the program is wrong, so you'll probably do the same error in the future.
Here is how YOUR code is working:

```
        //Declaring a reference to a App istance
        let app = App()
        //changing value of url of that app
        app.url = NSURL(string: "https://url2") as URL?
        //append that REFERENCE to istance
        apps.append(app)

        //Changing the value USING THE SAME REFERENCE 
        app.url = NSURL(string: "https://url3") as URL?

        //Appending the same reference, so both indexes are pointing to an istance with url "https://url3"
        apps.append(app)
```

the solution is:

```
        //Declaring a reference to a App istance
        let app = App()
        //changing value of url of that app
        app.url = NSURL(string: "https://url2") as URL?
        //append that istance
        apps.append(app)
        //Declaring a DIFFERENT reference to another App istance
        let app2 = App()
        //Changing the value of url for that istance
        app2.url = NSURL(string: "https://url3") as URL?
        //Appending the new app
        apps.append(app2)
```

You can also use a Struct for your App object. Structs will be copied by value, so you don't have to struggle with references. But IMHO the code will be less readable.

Comment: Thank you :-) . Every explanation is very important to me.